# List of workers that worked last week for the first time since April

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a list of workers that had the first shift last week since April 2021.
At the moment with the current query made below, I generate a list of workers that had only 1 shift last week, including also those who worked between April and last week. Do you know a way to create a more accurate list?

```
WITH time_frame AS
  (SELECT date_trunc('week',NOW())-interval '1 week'),

worker AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT booking.worker_id,
                   count(booking.id)
   FROM booking
   WHERE booking.start_time >= '04-01-2021'
   GROUP BY 1
   HAVING count(booking.id) = 1)


SELECT booking.worker_id
FROM worker
JOIN booking ON booking.worker_id = worker.worker_id
WHERE date_trunc('week',booking.start_time) =
    (SELECT *
     FROM time_frame)
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and add data to your question

Comment: The solution is : `NOT EXISTS(...)`

Comment: @nbk I made some adjustments to my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could simplify your current query as follow :

```
WITH worker AS
(SELECT DISTINCT worker_id, count(id)
   FROM booking
  WHERE start_time >= '04-01-2021'
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING count(id) = 1
)
SELECT b.worker_id
  FROM worker AS w
 INNER JOIN booking AS b 
    ON b.worker_id = w.worker_id
 WHERE date_trunc('week',b.start_time) = date_trunc('week',NOW())-interval '1 week')
```

Then the query to retrieve "on a weekly basis the list of the workers that had a job with us for the first time since April" can be :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (worker_id)
       worker_id, date_trunc('week',start_time) AS start_week
  FROM booking
 WHERE start_time >= '04-01-2021'
 ORDER BY worker_id, start_time ASC
```

Comment: Yes, I am currently preparing a query for my payroll. The outcome should show on a weekly basis the list of the workers that had a job with us for the first time since April. We are a staffing agency so workers on our database pick up jobs from time to time. @Edouard